# Technical review of code

Tags: apex, trigger, community, salesforce1-app, integration

Hey guys I am trying to create comprehensive checklist that will ensure best coding practice.
I have referred lot of sales-force documents and several blogs,still not sure what all things I have to add in order to ensure best code practice.
If anyone can help me with appropriate info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is highly opinion based. Of course there are a lot of best practices, but which one of these you'll want to follow is up to you and your team. I would suggest discussing this with the people you're going to work with and coming up with a set of conventions/requirements that you are all comfortable with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this answers your question : 
https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/05/developer-practices-checklist.html

Comment: Link only answers are not really suitable as the source can change making the answer invalid over time. - [answer]

Comment: Hi Dave - They are development practices in Salesforce and I din't want to spam by typing something here since it will be long list and pointed the Salesforce Learner to the right reference.